# Git submodule failure when building pages with Hugo

Tags: github-pages, git-submodules, hugo

I am trying to follow the steps on [Deployment as described in the manual](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/deployment/) of Academic-Hugo. The goal is to upload the Hugo website to GitHub pages.
However the following step fails and I have no clue what the issue could be:

```sh
$ git submodule add -f -b master https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git public
Reactivating local git directory for submodule 'public'.
fatal: 'origin/master' is not a commit and a branch 'master' cannot be created from it
Unable to checkout submodule 'public'
```

The `.gitmodules` file looks like this (not sure how relevant that is though...):

```sh
[submodule "themes/academic"]
    path = themes/academic
    url = https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic.git
[submodule "public"]
    path = public
    url = https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git
    branch = master
```

While `<USERNAME>` is my actual username of course. 
I am new to Hugo and github pages and would appreciate any pointers on how to resolve this or even where to look for the root of the issue.

Comment: Seems like it's reactivating a previously cached module and that might be in the origin of your problem. Have you tried cleaning up? One possible way is suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/myusuf3/7f645819ded92bda6677).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried to continue on anyway and it ended up working:

```
site $ hugo
site $ cd public/
site/public $ git add .
site/public $ git commit -m "initial build"
site/public $ git push # After this, all is well.
```

I did run a `git status` prior to pushing, but it had a warning (don't recall the message) and suggested I remove the remote origin. I ignored that too.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today and landed on this [site](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/hugo-101-deployment/18686/6?page=2) that has some useful info about deleting modules and re-doing the whole thing from start. Hope it might be useful to others as well.